# Masking a forwarding domain with no webspace for the domain to show

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, masking

I have a webspace on my own domain – let's call it `my-domain.com`. I'm hosting my friends website – let's call her Alice – on my webspaces subfolder `alice` which is therefore reachable under `my-domain.com/alice`.

My friend Alice decides to buy herself a Domain with Forwarding (but without webspace) and forwards it to the `my-domain.com/alice` URL. The forwarding is working but she wants the URL in the browser to look like it was hosted on her own webspace, e.g. like so: `alices-domain.com/start.html` (instead of what it looks like right now: `my-domain.com/alice/start.html`).

I found ways to mask a domain when one has success to the domains webspace (e.g. via `mod_rewrite`) – but there is **no webspace** in this case where I could put a `.htaccess` file in (just my own webspace).

Is there a way I can **still achieve masking without buying a new webspace** for the domain?

Comment: How did you create Alice's site on your server? Was it through a control panel? did you create a virtual host or did you copy files into a directory and just use it?

Comment: I just copied files into a directory.

Comment: Ok my answer should get you what you need then.

Answer (score 1):

If you just copied files to a sub folder then you will need to set it up as a **[virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)** in your apache config file so that your server will know where to go when you type in her domain name.  Vhosts are usually towards the bottom of the file. In centos it should be `httpd.conf` or ubuntu `apache2.conf` I believe.

Then just create another section for Alice's site.

e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@alices-domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/alices/folder/
     ServerName www.alices-domain.com
     ServerAlias alices-domain.com
     ErrorLog /var/www/alices-domain.com/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/alices-domain.com/requests.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Remove the forwarding on Alice's domain and then point Alice's DNS main `A record` to your servers IP address.

**UPDATE:**

To be clear and answer your last question. 
Create a subdomain like `alice.yousite.com` which will have a document root of `htdocs/alice`.

Now go to the DNS records for `www.alice-site.com` and add a CNAME. The **host** value will be `www` and then **points to (value)** `alice.yoursite.com`.

So when that propagates, you can go to `www.alice-site.com` and it will display `alice.yoursite.com`.

Comment: I'll give it a try. But I don't have access to the httpd.conf, just the `.htaccess` document (I'm using an online webspace service). The documentation says that basically everything should work that works on httpd.conf except for loading new modules. Is VirtualHost a module? I have no idea.

Comment: Nope, this didn't work for me. My whole website (all parts of it) get a 'internal error' when using the above snippet (with changed params) in the .htaccess file.

Comment: VirtualHost config can't be used in htaccess. Do you run a control panel since you are on a hosting plan?

Comment: What you most likely need to do is move her folder to a subdomain like alice.yoursite.com and you can keep the same webspace. Then you can redirect that subdomain to www.alice-site.com. You can use a CNAME dns record.

Comment: Well there's some kind of 'control panel' but very limited in its functionality. I'm now trying the approach with the subdomain you suggesting. I've added a CNAME entry named `alice.my-domain.com` with `www.alices-domain.com` as destination. Also I've created a 'new webserver' (that's what they call it) for the subdomain `alice.my-domain.com` that leads to the subfolder (`htdocs/alice`). Which URL does Alice's domain now have to point to? `alice.my-domain.com`? Have to wait to see any results ... sounds like a loop to me ... ^^